# Maven: Aggregated list of plugins

Tags: list, plugins, maven

Is there some aggregated list of Maven plugins?
Or at least list of lists.

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html
- http://mojohaus.org/plugins.html
- JBoss Maven plugins?

  - http://www.jboss.org/maven-jdocbook-plugin/
  - http://mojohaus.org/jboss-packaging-maven-plugin/
  - http://docs.jboss.org/jbossaop/docs/2.0.0.GA/docs/aspect-framework/reference/en/html/maven.html
- Nick Boldt's Jenkins plugins: https://github.com/nickboldt/maven-plugins
- what else?

Comment: Looks like you just put one together :-)

Comment: :) Right but I am hoping for some larger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always just search the central maven repository: 
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|11|maven.plugins

I also happened to come along this list on the maven website:

You could use the following search engines:

```
http://search.maven.org
http://repository.apache.org
http://www.artifact-repository.org
http://mvnrepository.com
http://www.mvnbrowser.com
http://www.jarvana.com
```